Handling deserialization of a paginated response from Rest API
I'm designing few Model classes in a Flutter project:
class ModelA { String titleA; /* ... */ }
class ModelB { String titleB; /* ... */ }

As suggested on other pages I've added "fromJson" methods to both:
class ModelA {
  String titleA;
  /* ... */
  factory ModelA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // json == {"titleA": "foo"}
    return switch (json) {
      {"titleA": String titleA} => ModelA(titleA),
      _ => throw const FormatException("failed to deserialize"),
    }
  }
}

(same for ModelB)
Next I need to handle the full JSON struct which can look like:

ModelA

{
  "count": 1,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    { "titleA": "foo" },
    { "titleA": "bar" }
  ]
}


ModelB

{
  "count": 1,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    { "titleB": "foo" },
    { "titleB": "bar" }
  ]
}

To do so the following class was created:
class Response <M> {
  int count;
  String? next;
  String? previous;
  List<M> results;
  Response(this.count, this.next, this.previous, this.results);
}

which I wanted the factory to be something like:
class Response <M> {
  int count;
  String? next;
  String? previous;
  List<M> results;
  Response(this.count, this.next, this.previous, this.results);
  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return switch (json) {
      {
        "count": int count,
        "next": String? next,
        "previous": String? previous,
        "results": List<dynamic> results,
      } => Response(count, next, previous, M.fromJsonDynList(results)),
      _ => throw const FormatException("failed to deserialize json into a Response"),
    };
  }
}

My question is: How do I make sure the M type will have a static method called fromJsonDynList ?
I know we cannot use "abstract" for that. Maybe inheritance? I'm new to the language. Open for any suggestion.

This approach will not work with Dart for two reasons:

Static methods are not part of a class interface. So there is no way to enforce that a class defines a specific static method or factory constructor.

There is also no provision for calling a method using a generic type e.g.  M.fromJsonDynList(results). This particular question has been asked before: see this answer.


The link above provides a workaround, namely to pass a function to the constructor of Response that can create an object of type M.

If you think the linked answer solves the issue, then why don't you just close-vote as such?

@DarkBee, I can't see a close button. And in my opinion, this  question might still be helpful since many programmers new to Dart are confused by this niche subject. However, the title has little to do with the actual question. It should rather be: How to make sure a generic type has a certain static method.

@DarkBee would it be possible to create a switch (M) where the cases are either ModelA or ModelB? that would at least allow me to manually call each of the factories correctly.
